# How to log into Windows 7 using ASCII codes instead of real password

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-layout

My friend uses a password with Farsi characters to log into Windows. However, while he was logged in he changed keyboard layout to US. Now while entering his password nothing happens.

How can I change keyboard layout to Farsi without logging into Admin account? Otherwise can I use ASCII codes to enter the characters to log in?

Comment: The simplest solution would be just to enable the default Administrator account and use that to change the password.

Comment: so i don't access nothing

Comment: First, try to find the language select button on the Windows logon screen. It should be in the upper-left corner. If it is not there, or if it does not offer to switch to Farsi, you can try the ALT+Numpad approach. (For that you will need to know the numerical Unicode values of the Farsi characters in the password.) While being in the password text box, hold down ALT and enter the numerical code of a character on the number pad (important!), then release the ALT key. When releasing the ALT key, the character will be inserted in the text box.

Comment: In ascii code my password is something like that ,77797484656665575454,but it doesn't work agarin ,are the ascii code of farsi and english same?

Comment: What are the codes of the actual Farsi characters? 77797484656665575454 is just one large number -- assuming each code being exactly two digits in this number (i am just guessing here) the word would be "MOJTABA966", without any Farsi/Persian characters... (now i know your password \*cough\* ;)